# Prevent app from Login/Sharing through Facebook App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

The problem is that when a post is shared using the Facebook App, the callback will always return {"cancelled":true}. That means that there is no way for our app to know if the user really shared the post or cancelled it. This is problematic as in the game, players are rewarded for sharing posts.

This issue has been acknowledged by the Facebook Team for more than a year now but they still didn't fix it.
Link to facebook dev bug thread: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598200610227965/

However if the Facebook App is not installed on the iOS/Android device, the Unity Facebook SDK will pop up a login/share notification in front of the app and its callback actually works so we are able to confirm a share.

My question is: Is there a way to force the app to call the popup notification instead of the Facebook App even if it is installed on the device?

Using: Unity 4.6 with Unity Facebook SDK 6.1

Comment: I haven't really used the Unity Facebook SDK too much, but I guess that the login window that pops up is a Webview. So, you could probably make a plugin to show a webview and handle the login from there, as well as the posting? In the plugin I wrote for Android, I used a lot of Graph API queries, and they seemed to return the right responses.

Comment: _“This is problematic as in the game, players are rewarded for sharing posts”_ – that is against [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy); you are not allowed to reward users for sharing. Please go read them.